# “Install alongside Windows 10” gone from Ubuntu installer

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I’m trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Win10, but after booting from the USB the option to install Ubuntu alongside the existing OS is gone.

I have shrunk existing partitions to create 90 GB worth of an unallocated space, which always did the trick. It doesn’t now: the option is gone.

Does it have something to do with the fact, that my disk has 4 partitions already? (c:/ windows 183 GB, 350 MB EFI System Partition, 619 MB OEM Partition and 202 GB Data partition, all preconfigured).

What do I do?

Comment: Is your computer set to use RAID+AHCI mode for the SATA drives?  If so, that's why you're getting issues with the "existing OS option" being gone - Ubuntu can't operate in Intel's RAID+AHCI mode.

Comment: How do I find out?

Comment: You'll have to boot into your BIOS and find out from the settings it says.  Unfortunately every BIOS is different so I can't give you more useful instructions than this, and if you change RAID+AHCI mode to just AHCI mode Windows won't work either.  You'd have to do some changes to make it actually recognize the dual boot.

Comment: Please take a look at these 4 pics: https://ibb.co/Cm0mYg7
https://ibb.co/VYFzqjh
https://ibb.co/BGZ7kPF
https://ibb.co/hHS9qjT

Comment: Does it tell you anything on the matter?

Comment: It'd probably be under that Storage subcategory

Comment: There you go: https://ibb.co/gwFQ8Pg What do you think?